# Remove invalid data based on particular pattern SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sample data like shown below

```
------------------------------------------------
| ID |          Column 1           | Column 2 |
------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 0229-10010                  |Valid     |
------------------------------------------------
| 2  |                       20483 |InValid   |
------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 319574R06-STAT              |Valid     |
------------------------------------------------
| 4  | ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,      |InValid   |
------------------------------------------------
| 5  | "PBOM-SSE, CHAMBER"         |Valid     |
------------------------------------------------
| 6  | ""PBOM-SSE, CHAMBER         |InValid   |
------------------------------------------------
| 7  | "PBOM-SSE CHAMBER",         |InValid   |
------------------------------------------------
| 8  | #DRM-1102.Z                 |InValid   |
------------------------------------------------
| 9  | DRM#1102.Z                  |Valid     |
------------------------------------------------
| 10 |OEM-2-202 4079 KALREZ        |Valid     |
------------------------------------------------
| 11 |-OEM2202 4079 KALREZ#        |InValid   |
------------------------------------------------
```

What i want to do is i need to create a pattern in such a way that i need to fetch only invalid data. Just for representation i have mentioned Valid and Invalid. In my table i don't have any flag as such.

Here the trick is same, `wildcard character`s appearing at different places makes different sense. Consider record `ID-5` and `Id-6`. In both the cases wildcard characters are same, but the position decides whether its valid or not. Again position is also not so clear. I guess you can make out why particular record in column 1 is valid and invalid. In `record 8`, `'#'` before that item doesn't makes sense, where as # after Alphabet makes sense (in record 9).

In record 2, there are lot of blank spaces before number, that's why its invalid, but that doesn't mean that space itself is wild card.
I have written query like below.

```
SELECT [PartNumber]
FROM [IBSSSystems].[dbo].[Part]
WHERE (PartNumber LIKE '%[?;.,$^@&*{}:"<>/|\ %'']%'
       OR PartNumber LIKE '%[%'
       OR PartNumber LIKE '%]%')
```

The above query understands that whenever it see any wildcard character in a record , it fetches that. But I need the query in such a way that it understands and fetches only invalid data. I guess there will be lot of `And` and `Or` in the resulting query, but i'm confused. I hope you can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to a world of pain. In modern SQL Server you can use regex - but otherwise (and even then) This is NOT the type of work I would do in SQL. This is much better suited for a "pull all then run filters client side" in particular because there it is easier to debug those filters with unit tests ;)

Comment: I understand and agree that, but most worrying part is in that table there are 4924574 records.. And counting on... :)

Comment: Not really that bad - you wont do that too often and you never have to store them (data reader, run through them). It is a LOT more efficient from a programmer side. Loading 50 million records should not take more than a minute or two max - unless you run that over the internet or have REALLY crappy network equipment (like 100mbit adapters that noone uses anymore). Yes, it is slow - but you have to choose your battles and this is not something I would love to do in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT [PartNumber]
FROM [IBSSSystems].[dbo].[Part]
WHERE (PartNumber LIKE '[^A-Za-z0-9"]%' ESCAPE '\'          -- When the First character is special charater its InValid ( " is an exception)
        OR PartNumber LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9" ]' ESCAPE '\'     -- When the Last character is special charater its InValid ( " is an exception, also trailing spaces are exception)
        OR PartNumber LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9 ][^A-Za-z0-9 ]%'   -- When there are two or more consecutive special charaters its InValid        
        OR PartNumber LIKE '%[\^\[\]\\_?;$@&*{}:<>/|''~`]%'  ESCAPE '\' -- Add characters here which do not allowed to have any occurrence in the string
       )
```